# Why pandas data frame containing multiple columns say 10 is of dimension 2?

Tags: pandas, numpy

No of dimensions is equal to the number of features. Isn't that true? Every row can be represented with 10 values of different attributes, makes it 10 dimensional. Am i correct in this understanding.

Comment: pandas DataFrames have two dimensions, 'rows' and 'columns'.  The number of columns doesn't affect the number dimensions.

Comment: What did you mentioned is the `size` of DF not its dimension. As @ScottBoston said, Pandas DFs have two dimensions.

Comment: When we talk about word2vector, we say a word is converted into a n-dimensional vector. Eg. 300 dimensions. Can't we say these are values of 300 attributes? and if we say we have 10 words then we could have a dataframe of size 10*300 which will then be 2 dimensional. Confused between these two thoughts.

Comment: You are confusing the dimension definition in feature space vs. dimension of a pandas dataframe. They are defined separately. While the dimensions of a feature space is defined by the number of features, the dimensions of a dataframe is two (rows and columns). Same word, different definitions.

Comment: @Ehsan So you are saying no of features or attributes is equal to the no of dimensions only when we talk about feature space?  Other than this all these attributes are nothing but columns which can be represented in a 2d tabular format?

Comment: @RahulMandal Exactly. You got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused with the size of a dataframe.
The number of dimensions can be thought of as the number of directions your data spans.

For example, the number of rows is a dimension where your data extends "downwards".
The number of columns is another dimension where your data extends "rightwards".

This makes the convention data table or excel sheet a "2-dimensional" dataframe. Now imagine if we stacked 3 of these "2-dimensional" dataframes flat on top of each other like pancakes. This gives us a 3-dimensional dataframe which can be identified by (X, Y, Z).

X - number of rows of each dataframe
Y - number of features of each dataframe
Z - number of (X, Y) dataframes stacked on each other

and this is generally how image data comes in.

There is a page that highlights the differences between size and dimensions of a dataframe here.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-df-size-df-shape-and-df-ndim/